# Angular ui router : Change state on double click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is that possible to change the state when doubleclicking on an element?

I have a view with two custom view inside. One for a grid, and one for a form. The form need some id passed in the URL to get to know which entity to edit. I use angular-ui-router to do that, it work when I use a `<a>` element with `ui-sref`. But I want to achieve the same behavior when I db-click on a row of my grid.

Comment: Provide a plunkr of what you have currently.

Comment: sure..use an event handler instead of `ui-sref` and in handler call `$state.go()` with proper params set

Comment: Thanks. I'm new I'm discovering all the features. I will investigate that `$state.go()` it look great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something with the [double click event](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDblclick) and [$state.go()](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) should do it.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-dblclick="$ctrl.goToTargetState()">>

    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
function goToTargetState(){
    $state.go('my-target-state');
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work in current version. Please update your answer